# Any recipient can modify an order confirmation mail, right? Does this ever matter?

Tags: email

I have boldly stated that there is no way to 'write protect' an e-mail, but want to be sure of my ground.

Surely, if Joe Bloggs receives an e-mail from me (or my e-commerce site or a web application written by me) saying -  "I will sell you X for $10 ", he *could* modify that price to, say, $9, and forward it to someone or save the e-mail, but so what?

The original e-mail will always be accessible and traceable on mail servers and a copy in mail clients of all recipients.

So, therefore, there is no need to do this. And it is not possible anyway.

Is this true?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to rationalise not doing a particular bit of work. Care to explain the context behind this question?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I'm writing a simple calculator whereby the user completes an HTML form, we do some maths on the $_POST-ed array variables and end up with an 'offer', which we then mail to a prospective cc ourselves using the PHP mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); function. The question has been asked by someone in the client company, and to be honest I have never been asked this before. So just sense checking.

Comment: Interesting. I can think of a few issues, but I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Why don't you just sign the email?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Because, in general, "John from Accounts" isn't going to have a clue what PGP is, let alone how to verify the signature's authenticity.

Comment: @Polynomial: John doesn't have to. If John says it should be $10, but customer says it's $9, then someone with some technical clue can tell the real one from the forgery through the signature. John doesn't have to be that person.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is one of integrity, whereby a recipient can take an email you sent them, alter the contents, then forward them to a 3rd party. This might be problematic if an agent or middle-man decides to bloat up the prices and take a cut off the top.

There are two ways of solving this:

1. Digitally sign the message using a technology such as PGP, and ensure that all potential recipients are aware that you **always** sign your mail. This provides proof of authenticity, and gives you grounds to refute claims by any 3rd party.
2. Provide an out-of-band copy of some or all of the content. This could be achieved by logging quote details on the server, along with a "quote ID", which is sent with the email. This gives you a record of the quote, along with the details that were used and the price that was shown.

I would go for option 2 in your situation, since it doesn't require clients to be tech savvy.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up. I agree that option 2 is preferential in this situation. Much appreciated.

Comment: For particular integrity with your quote ID system, sign a concatenation of the previous quote's signature and the current quote on your quote server. Nobody will ever have to see it unless it comes down to a legal challenge, but having a chain like that goes a long way to proving you didn't modify your auth system. Additional help comes from write-only archival and/or a 3rd party [timestamp service](https://www.google.com/search?q=timestamp+signature+service)

Comment: I'm not sure how #2 will really help.  Sleazy middlemen can simply delete the link to your quote page at the same time as they change the value in the forwarded message.

Comment: @DanNeely But in that event you have recourse to demonstrate good faith on your behalf, in case the customer comes crying to you.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked in 2013.  At that time, [DKIM](http://dkim.org/) was not nearly as widely deployed as it is now in 2020.  Nowadays, most major email service providers (e.g. gmail, yahoo mail, etc.) DKIM-sign messages sent through their service.

DKIM was designed as a solution to combat spam and spoofing, but a side effect of DKIM (which can be seen either as a benefit or a consequence, depending on your perspective) is that a DKIM signature on a message can be used to prove the message's authenticity, after it has been delivered.

If a message is DKIM-signed by the sender, and the recipient changes the message after receiving the message, then this would break the DKIM signature.  Of course, the recipient could change the message, and remove the DKIM signature (making it appear that the message was never DKIM-signed).  However, if the message contains a DKIM signature, and the message has not been altered, then (barring a compromise of the signer's private key or a nefarious use of the signer's private key) the recipient can prove that the message was sent (at the time shown in the timestamp) by verifying the DKIM signature.

For more information, see https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2020/11/16/ok-google-please-publish-your-dkim-secret-keys/